# How can I detect when a post/page is being filtered in Wordpress by Advanced Access Manager (AAM) Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I detect when a post/page is being filtered by this plugin?

Advanced Access Manager
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

The goal I have is to remove restricted posts from the wordpress loop, right now it shows the post title and the following excerpt:

```
To view the contents of this page, you must be authenticated and have the required access level.
```

I can't seem to find a variable or array key/value that would allow me to remove use some conditional code to remove the restricted posts from the loop.

Using:

```
<?php print_r($post); ?>
```

inside the loop shows the original post content without it being filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, found a post meta value using:

```
 <?php get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wpac_restricted_to', false); ?>
```